# Access controller methods from ActionCable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable

The example code from [doc](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html):

```
# app/channels/web_notifications_channel.rb
class WebNotificationsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_for current_user
  end
end
```

I have method `current_user` in `ApplicationController`. There error undefined method `current_user` id `subscribed` method of course becouse `WebNotificationsChannel` is not derived from `ApplicationController`. What doc mean? Or what I have missed?

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42452474/4587148) .

Comment: Thanks. Some one also mention useful link to the doc but removed the comment. The link was: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/actioncable/ActionCable/Connection/Base