# how can i call controller action after channel streaming?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, actioncable

my channel:

```
class DevicesChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from 'datas_channel', coder: ActiveSupport::JSON
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
    raise NotImplementedError
  end

  def receive
    data = DeviceInformation.create(message: "oks")
    ActionCable.server.broadcast("datas_channel", data)
  end
end
```

To send request for subscribe, did:

```
{
  "command": "subscribe",
  "identifier": "{\"channel\":\"DevicesChannel\"}"
}
```

And, to write message:

```
{
    "command": "message",
    "identifier": "{\"channel\":\"DevicesChannel\"}",
    "data": "{\"message\":\"Hello world\", \"action\": \"receive\"}"
}
```

On above request, it works well. it call receive method and works well.

But i want to call controller action 'Create' i.e

```
class DeviceInformationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    data = DeviceInformation.create(message: 'Hello world')
    ActionCable.server.broadcast("datas_channel", data)
  end
end
```

is it possible to do? any help would be really appreciated. I am new to web socket API

Comment: Why d you want to do that? 
can you create a method inside model to directly use it inside controller and channel so that you can achieve same functionality in both controller and channel?

Comment: i just want to make sure, is it possible to do so or not?

Comment: You will run into some errors if there's any auth or session related logic in your controllers (In most cases there will be) and you can read this post for more clarity :) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451889/how-do-i-get-current-user-in-actioncable-rails-5-api-app/42452474#42452474

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the way Rails-core do integration testing:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb
(read the code ActionDispatch::Integration::Session#process)

I did a demo (get all targets - TargetsController#index)

```rb
class DevChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  # ...
  def receive(data)
    session = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)
    path = ENV.fetch("APPLICATION_HOST") + Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.targets_path
    session.get(path)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast("DevChannel", session.response.body)
  end
end
```