# undefined local variable or method `cookies' for ApplicationCable::Connection:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I'm using ActionCable (ruby on rails v6.1.4) and I'm trying to access my cookies with the Connection class, but I keep getting the "undefined local variable or method `cookies' for ApplicationCable::Connection:Class" error.

My cookies work without an issue in development and production. I only experience this when working with ActionCable.

I've followed the instructions of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59791408/10475726), but I still get the error.

Here is the class:

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    include ActionController::Cookies

    if cookies.signed[:user_id]
      puts "User found"
    else
      puts "User not found"
    end
  end
end
```

In case there's an issue with my `cable.yml`, here is the file:

```
development:
  adapter: async

test:
  adapter: test

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: backend_production
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [solution](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.3.4/classes/ActionCable/Connection/Base.html).

I needed an identification index, along with a connect and a disconnect method.
You're able to access cookies within those methods.

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user #identification index

    def connect
      self.current_user = User.find_by(id: cookies.encrypted['_cookie_name']['user_id'])
    end

    def disconnect
      # Any cleanup work needed when the cable connection is cut.
    end
  end
end
```